# How the group can view the Standard and Custom object Chatter feed post?

Tags: trigger, chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, feeditem

In the screenshot no-1, we can post anything via chatter feed also we can able to share the post to Group which we created. Then all the group members can view the post. But in the screenshot no-2, opportunity object we have Chatter feed there also we can post but the thing is, the post only can be viewed by the record followers. But My client wants the same feature which I have highlighted in Screenshot no-1 in other objects (Accounts,Contacts and Opportunities) as well. So that the group can view all the post. I guess this can be done only by using triggers. Can anyone help me out in this.

[image: Chatter Page setting]

[image: Opportunity Chatter Feed]

Comment: Alternative to custom code, would be to use the free Salesforce labs appExchange app : Cloud Swarm. With this you can configure it to make all or certain users automatically follow all or certain opportunities, take a look: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003GGRwEAO

Comment: @dacology, That is true. In this case the opportunity feed will be visible only for the record followers.But my requirement is Opportunity feed should be visible to all the users in the particular group. Hope my question is clear.